# Sequentially splitting the same list according to the letters it contains in Python

Tags: python, regex, list, split

I am trying to sequentially split a word based on the letters it contains:

```
import re

word = "Discovery"
split_pattern = re.compile(r'[?=r]') 
new_word = split_pattern.split(word)
print(new_word)

split_pattern2 = re.compile(r"[?=e]")
new_word2 = split_pattern2.split(str(new_word)) 
print(new_word2)

['Discove', 'y']
["['Discov", "', 'y']"]
```

I have three questions:

How can I maintain the r on the end of Discove and split to the right? (i.e. 'Discove', 'r', 'y' for the subsequent part)

How do I main a single list instead of getting a list within a list with double sets of square brackets?

Why in the second 'digest' is Discov covered by an apostrophe and single quotation mark?

Comment: Try `str.partition()` instead.

Comment: when you do `str(new_word)` you get `"['Discove', 'y']"` as output (outer is double quotes because string value contains single quotes)... and then you are trying to split that on `?` or `=` or `e` of which `e` is present, so you get two elements in result... try printing `new_word2[0]` and `new_word2[1]`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think what you wanted to do was `re.split(r'(r)', 'Discovery')` to get `['Discove', 'r', 'y']` as the result, if not please explain

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got it right but I guess [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) will do what you want. See:

```py
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:16:48) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'Discovery'.partition('r')
('Discove', 'r', 'y')
>>> 'Discovery'.partition('e')
('Discov', 'e', 'ry')
>>>
```

You can also check [`str.rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Would this still work if I want to split multiple incidences of the same character?

Comment: The `str.partiton()` method returns a tuple. But if you want a list instead you can slightly modify it it `list('Discovery'.partition('r'))`.

Answer (score 0):

for multiple instances you can use `str.split()` function in the following way:

```
char = 'r'
text = 'DiscoveryTurbo'
opt = []
for x in text.split(char)
   opt.extend([x, char]) 
opt = opt[:-1]
```

o/p:

```
['Discove', 'r', 'yTu', 'r', 'bo']
```

Comment: you could use a capture group instead `re.split(r'(r)', 'DiscoveryTurbo')`